# Can I use AWS IoT Core Things with sigv4 or I need a X.509 client certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, x509, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, sigv4

I have been using sigv4 to connect my devices to the AWS IoT Core rule engine through HTTPS requests. Now I am interested in creating an IoT Core Thing to manage my devices, but to do so, I need an X.509 certificate.
Can I create an IoT Core Thing without an X.509 client certificate, and how? How to specify, in the device HTTPS request, which device belongs to which thing?
(I can not put certificates on my device)

Answer (score 1):

You can create iot thing in AWS IoT without a certificate. Then to connect to AWS IoT Core, you can use custom authentication with username and password (custom lambda authorizer).
Here is the documentation that explains it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-authentication.html